# Why is there no exact formula for the product of first n natural numbers like the formula for the sum of first n natural numbers?

Tags: number-theory

I know we have quite good approximation for the product of first n natural numbers like the Stirling's approximation. But my question is why we don't have an exact formula(note: not an approximation) for the product of first n natural numbers like the formula for the sum of first n natural numbers which is n(n+1)/2.

Comment: The product of first n natural numbers is n! (n factorial)

Comment: This depends on what you consider a "formula," which is quite vague. A lot of people will consider the factorial so basic that $n!$ in itself is a formula. (just like you consider $n^2$ a formula.)

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["Why is there no explicit formula for the factorial?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/454689/409) There may be others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no explicit formula for the factorial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454689/why-is-there-no-explicit-formula-for-the-factorial). There might be others as Blue indicated in the above comment, but I believe this one mentioned there is a good duplicate target.

Comment: Here is an analogy: For the sum $(s_n)$ of natural numbers, the associated difference equation is $$s_n - s_{n-1} = n, $$ which is loosely a discrete analogue of the differential equation $y'(x)=x$. This equation has a solution $y(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2$. On the other hand, for the product $(p_n)$ of natural numbers, the associated difference equation is $$p_n - p_{n-1} = (n-1)p_n$$, and any non-trivial solution of its continuous analogue $y'(x) = (x-1)y(x)$ cannot be written in terms of polynomial, necessitating a new function for describing the solutions. A similar thing happens to $(p_n)$.

Comment: I mean is not there shortcut formula for calculating n! like n(n+1)/2  is a shortcut formula for calculating the sum of first n natural numbers.

Comment: @bidish . What you get when you use the formula n(n+1)/2 is a quadratic function in terms on n which is exactly evaluates to the sum of first n natural numbers. So what you are doing is plotting the curve x(x+1)/2. And then saying that at when x is an integer then the value coincides with the sum of first x natural number.  If you want to do something similar you have to go for $\Gamma(x)$. So that for non negative integer $x$ you get $\Gamma(x+1)=x!$. Now for approximating it using an explicit formula which is not exact. You have to go for something like stirlings formula.

Comment: I believe the question is more about why is there no closed form expression for n!